# How can we use IAM Roles in AWS that can be used to access API in an application?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

How can I use the role feature to access the AWS API in an application? How can I implement this use case?

I am able to fetch the credentials by launching an ec2 role based instance.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create IAM Roles for Amazon EC2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753372/how-can-i-create-iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2)

Comment: As a warning, do not use comments to ask for others to answer your question. I'm removing all of these comments across the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IAM Rules are used to manage access to AWS services and resources. It is *not* meant to be used as an applicative authorization engine. From [the documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/):

> AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) enables you to securely
>   control access to AWS services and resources for your users. Using
>   IAM, you can create and manage AWS users and groups and use
>   permissions to allow and deny their access to AWS resources.